# Configure Windows 2012 VHD to boot in Windows 2008 R2 Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, vhd

I have a server running Windows 2008 R2 and Hyper-V. I use this server routinely to create Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 7 VHDs to boot within Hyper-V and natively.

I have created a VHD, used imagex to apply an image of Windows Server 2012, made the partition active for the VHD, and attached it as Z:. This is the normal process I follow when creating a Windows 2008 R2 VHD for booting from Hyper-V or natively. The next step to allow it to boot in Hyper-V is normally:

- Open a command prompt and change to the directory at Z:\Windows\System32
- Enter the following command and press return `BCDboot.exe Z:\Windows /s Z:\`

This last step does not appear to work with the Windows 2012 VHD as it does with Windows 2008 R2. I also tried: `bcdboot Z:\Windows /s Z:\ /f ALL`

The verbose output in both instances is:

```
BFSVC Error: BfspSetSecurityDescriptor(\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolume8\Boot) 
failed! Last Error = 0x8 BFSVC Error: Error copying boot files from Z:\Windows\boot\PCAT 
to \?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolume8\Boot! Last Error = 0x8 Failure when attempting 
to copy boot files.
```

Is there a different command or syntax that needs to be used when working with Windows 2012 images?

I can create the blank VHD attach it to a new virtual machine in Hyper-V and install Windows 2012 then configure it to boot natively but would prefer to use the same process for all OSes.